# XPath to select elements between elements based on content?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

Given the following HTML, what XPath will select all `a` elements between the one with `Mac / Macbooks` anchor text and the one with `More` anchor text?

```
<dd> 
  <ol> 
    <li> 
      <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=9">DO NOT WANT 1</a> (164)
    </li>  
    <li> 
      <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=10">Mac / Macbooks</a> (165)
    </li>  
    <li> 
      <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=18">iPhone</a> (459)
    </li>  
    <li> 
      <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=20">iPad</a> (221)
    </li>  
    <li> 
      <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=486">Watch</a> (129)
    </li>  
    <li> 
      <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=16">iPod</a> (85)
    </li>  
    <li> 
      <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=574">More</a> (69)
    </li> 
    <li> 
      <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=575">DO NOT WANT 2</a> (70)
    </li>  
  </ol> 
</dd>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To select elements between two elements based on content

1. Use tests against string values to identify the end points.

   - `//a[.='Mac / Macbooks']` selects the *start element*.
   - `//a[.='More']` selects the *end element*.
2. Use the [preceding and following axis](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes) to select elements
   between other elements.
3. Decide whether the endpoints should be included or excluded.

   **Excluded case:**

   ```
   //a[preceding::a[.='Mac / Macbooks'] and following::a[.='More']]
   ```

   **Included case** (just like the excluded case but with the endpoints added via `or`):

   ```
   //a[preceding::a[.='Mac / Macbooks'] and following::a[.='More'] 
                    or .='Mac / Macbooks'
                    or .='More']
   ```

   Note that XPath has no `following-or-self` and `preceding-or-self` 
   axes, so we add the endpoints explicitly.

   The results for the **excluded case** are:

   ```
   <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=18">iPhone</a>
   <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=20">iPad</a>
   <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=486">Watch</a>
   <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=16">iPod</a>
   ```

   The results for the **included case** are:

   ```
   <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=10">Mac / Macbooks</a>
   <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=18">iPhone</a>
   <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=20">iPad</a>
   <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=486">Watch</a>
   <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=16">iPod</a>
   <a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple?cat=574">More</a>
   ```

   Note that in both cases the results returned are in document order.

Answer (score 1):

Select based on the content, which is "More"..

This might work? It's untested.

`//a[.="More"]`

Comment: thanks it works, but i want to have a tags from Mac/macbook to more,

Comment: it just selects <a> tag which have more, i want to have <a> tags from Macbook to More , but in my code it select <a> tags of the whole html page please help

Comment: Upvoting because this is a good start and because it elicited comments from OP that were very helpful in discerning intent.